# Different Crontabs?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I installed ubuntu desktop on my Amazon EC2 instance using `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and did the rest of the setup.

I logged using TighVNC viewer.

To my surprise, when I do `crontab -e` on my desktop terminal it's a different file than when I do `crontab -e` on my SSH (using Putty).

Comment: Each user has their own crontab.  Is the desktop running as a different user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the crontabs of 2 different users. Looks like your VNC sessions and SSH session are using different user to access the same machine. Try

```
sudo crontab -l -u <username>
```

to list the crontab of a user

```
sudo crontab -l -u root

sudo crontab -l -u ubuntu
```